# How to fix SSL error in Python which connected with Javascript?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, ssl, https

I am putting my python which doing the web crawler and javascript code together .
However,there is an error coming : `"HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.twreporter.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /topics?page=13 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))"`

I tried to `import ssl` in my python code, but once I did it, it got :

```
undefined:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
```

even the code only has :

```
import json
import ssl
print(json.dumps("1234"))
```

How could I fix this ?

here is part of my javascript code :

```
let { PythonShell } = require('python-shell')
let options = {
    mode: 'json',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    scriptPath: './python',
};
PythonShell.run('pythontest.py', options, function (err, results, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
    console.log(results);
}
```

compelet error in javascript:

```
undefined:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at PythonShell.asJson (D:\【code】\database\Reporter\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:358:21)
    at D:\【code】\database\Reporter\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:310:42
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PythonShell.recieveInternal (D:\【code】\database\Reporter\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:306:15)
    at PythonShell.receiveStderr (D:\【code】\database\Reporter\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:290:21)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\【code】\database\Reporter\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:108:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
```

OS: windows 10

python: python 3.7

compiler: visual studio code

By the way, the python code can work alone on my computer or google colab.